# How to add zip entry with utf-8 name to zip

Tags: java, zip

I have a method which adds inputStream to zip as an entry:

```
private void addToZip(InputStream is, String filename) throws Exception {
    try {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when the filename contains an UTF-8 char like áé... In zip file it will be saved as `?????` and when I unzip it in ubuntu 12.10 it looks like: `N├бstroje` instead of `Nástroje`.

For this example I used jdk6 but now I've also tried jdk7:

```
zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

But with no success.

I also tried Apache Commons Zip and set encoding but also with no success.

So how I can add this file with unicode symbols in filename to zip ?

Comment: I've had the same problem some time ago. I used non-Unicode charset, specific to the local language (Cp866). And it worked fine.

Comment: so instead of Nástroje I should save entry as Nastroje ? This is last options... how you convert it ?

Comment: That application was intended to run in Windows system. And I used `Cp866` encoding, to support russian characters in filenames in zip archives and view them correctly when I view zip file contents. And it worked. Is there a non-unicode charset, that supports your language symbols? Try to use it, instead of utf-8.

Comment: yes: iso-8859-2 but when I use this then á is converting to c

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea how to overcome that.

Comment: never mind. I solve my problem but I have no idea why it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems this line solved my problem:

```
        zos.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.ALWAYS);
```

can someone explain me what is this doing and why it works ?

Comment: Unicode Extra Fields are an extension to the zip format to use additional custom fields in the entry headers to store a UTF-8 version of the file name alongside the default local encoding version.  Archive unpackers that support this extension will use the UTF-8 name from the extra fields in preference to the standard name field.

Comment: I can't find the method setCreateUnicodeExtraFields inside ZipOutputStream

Comment: @BogdanSamondros this is an Apache Ant API ZipOutputStream

Answer (score 3):

Zip archive by default uses DOS(OEM) codepage to store filenames.
Linux/unix implementations uses system codepage when unpacking. Mac OS uses utf-8 by default.
So in your case filename is stored correctly, but Linux archiver doesn't understand it.

Comment: but when I create zip in linux (right click and compress) it create archvive with entry name contains ?? but when I extract it there is correct name

Comment: Sure, because it uses the same encoding.

Comment: my system codepage is UTF-8 and when I use apache common archive and set endocing to utf-8 then it still doesnt work

Comment: The easiest way to check is to use hex editor/viewer on your archive. Windows zip archive codepage depends on your locale, for Russian it is CP-866, for other languages it should be something like CP-8xx